# Disable Wifi when battery voltage is 3.4

Tags: android

For my device I want disable wifi when battery voltage level comes down to 3.4.

How to know the battery voltage is 3.4 programmatically?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) if it doesn't have to be self-made...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` sticky intent and read the voltage from there:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = getContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int voltage = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
if(voltage>0 && voltage<3400){
    //disable wifi
}
```

Comment: Thaks for ur valuable answer. I'll try this :)

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept it (and so closing the question) if you estimate it's a correct answer.