# How can i disable wifi when battery level is less 10%?

Tags: android, android-wifi, togglebutton, batterylevel

I'm writing an application that when the battery level is less of 10% the wifi connection (if activate) will disable. This is what i want but not what i am able to do :). I've created a toggle and when pressed the wifi stops and vice versa if press again the wifi turns on in this way:

```
    public void getRisparmio(View view) {
    // is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    if (on) {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } else {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(tru);
    }
    }
```

in this way i get the battery level:

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
```

what i want is something like

```
    public void getRisparmio(View view) {
    // is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    if (on) {
    if (level < 10){
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
    } else {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    }
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560341/disable-wifi-when-battery-voltage-is-3-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check battery level when you click on button:

```
public void getRisparmio(View view) {

   .....
   IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
   Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
   int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
   if (level<10){
       ......
   }
   .......
}
```

If you want to disable wifi when battery level is low,you can register a Broadcast receiver with with this `IntentFilter Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`.

```
public class BatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           boolean batteryLow = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
           if (batteryLow){
                  ....
                   level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                   if (level<xx) {
                     //call your code
                     //wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                   }
           }
    }
}
```

In your Activity in `onResume()` you can register your broadcast receiver

```
BatteryReceiver receiver = new BatteryReceiver();
IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter();
inf.addAction(BatteryReceiver); 
registerReceiver(receiver, inf);
```

Remember to unregister receiver in `onPause()`.

Otherwise you can register in Manifest.xml

```
<reciever android:name=".BatteryReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</reciever>
```

Comment: mmh can you make an example please? sorry i'm pretty noob actually with android. How can i implement this `Intent` in my condition?

Comment: Later i try..but as you can see i've got a toggle button.. Can i "insert" your code inside my button in some way? Is it possible? What i want to do is that on click, if the battery level (or when the battery level) is < batteryLow (following your example), then turns the wifi off. Understand now?

Comment: Thank you, another one question.. When i push the toggle the condition goes on background? I mean, for example; the battery level is 25%..i click the button and i go out from my app.. When the battery level is at 10% automatically start the condition? or start at the moment when i push the toggle button? I don't know if you understand.. (sei italiano) ?

Comment: If I understand your question or rather your intention, you want to use the button as a way to enable this "smart wifi management mode". So as soon as the user clicks on the toggle, I assume you should check if the current battery level is low and if yes turn off wifi. Else register for the BATTERY_LOW intent and on receiving the broadcast, check if the button is still "enabled" and turn off wifi. If button has been disabled, deregister the broadcast receiver.